# [DataDirect][ODBC lib] error when refreshing WEBI report

Tags: business-objects, webi

I am using the Web Intelligence Rich Client 4.2 SP3 Patch 3, I created a report and save it on WEBI. After I open the report in WEBI, when I click Refresh, it gives me the following error:

`The following database error occurred: [DataDirect][ODBC lib] System information file not found. Please check the ODBCINI environment variable.. For information about this error, please refer to SAP Knowledge Base Article 2054721 on the SAP Support Portal. (IES 10901) (Error: INF )`

What is the problem and how do I fix it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the WebI Rich Client needs both 32-bit and 64-bit ODBC data sources with the same name on the machine on which it is running. Then you will need a 64-bit ODBC data source with the same name on the server in order to be able to run the WebI report via the BI Launchpad.

This [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942976/odbc-administrator-tool-displays-both-the-32-bit-and-the-64-bit-user-d) discusses how to get to the 32-bit and 64-bit ODBC Administrator Tools.